# K-Fold cross validating with random forest - how to correctly fit model to every fold?

Tags: training, cross-validation

So I have created K-Folds from my data using this code:

```
X = rfedata.drop(['target'],axis=1)
Y = rfedata['target']

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)

KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X.take(list(train_index),axis=0), X.take(list(test_index),axis=0)
    y_train, y_test = Y.take(list(train_index),axis=0), Y.take(list(test_index),axis=0)
```

Now I would like to train my model. By doing the below, does the model get trained on every fold, or is it just 1 fold? If not, would you have an idea of how to train 1 model on every fold?

```
model9 = RandomForestRegressor()
model9.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: As long as the call to `model.fit` is included within the for loop the model is being trained with every split.

Comment: Thanks @Oxbowerce for your comment. Right, but would that not overwrite the training with each fold? Or would it be trained generally on every fold and overall on all data?

Comment: @Oxbowerce sorry my comment may have not made sense. What I meant was that, on every iteration of training, wouldn't that cause the model to forget the previous training and be trained as of new? Or would the model remember each previous training and so as a result be trained on all data? Hope it's clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Oxbowerce, make sure to include fit inside the loop and it will train your model again. You can also initialize the object again as follows

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X.take(list(train_index),axis=0), X.take(list(test_index),axis=0)
    y_train, y_test = Y.take(list(train_index),axis=0), Y.take(list(test_index),axis=0)

    # Train the model for each fold
    model9 = RandomForestRegressor()
    trained_model = model9.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Evaluate the model for each fold

    # Save the trained model

    # And so on!
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks @DevashishPrasad! but would that not overwrite the training with each iteration? Or would it be trained generally on every fold and overall on all data? Also would it make sense to use the model9.predict(X) outside the for loop? Since we already have a model trained on all folds..

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the training and that is what needs to be done in K-Fold cross-validation. You need to train K separate models and evaluate them separately on K distinct validation sets. You can choose to save these K models (updated the answer) or append these models in a list or maintain them however you want.

Comment: So if you have trained K separate models then which model would you run model9.predict(X) on? Wouldn't you need a general model that is trained on all the folds to do that? Or would you predict using the best performing model? That doesn't make sense because then you are missing out on the rest of the data...

Comment: K-Fold cross-validation is not a training methodology, it is actually a model selection methodology. For eg if you want to choose between Decision Tree and Naive Bayes models, you will run K-Fold cross-validation to check how much accuracy you might expect using both of these models. For eg NB performed well than DT, so you might want to train a single big DT on the whole dataset and then use that model as your final model. Or you might use an ensemble of K-trained NB models and use majority vote or average votes to make final predictions.

Comment: The main idea of K-Fold Cross-Validation is to evaluate and compare models using an unbiased and fair test set.